# Woocommerce static email attachment

Tags: email, woocommerce

Is there a way i can attach the static pdf file: https://smagdansk.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SMAGdansk-Fortrydelsesformular.pdf to all my woocommerce order complete emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested OK with **WooCommerce 3.5.4**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email($attachments, $id, $object) {

    $your_pdf_path = 'https://smagdansk.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/SMAGdansk-Fortrydelsesformular.pdf';

    if (!class_exists('WP_Http'))
        include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php' );
    $http = new WP_Http();
    $response = $http->request($your_pdf_path);
    if ($response['response']['code'] != 200) {
        return false;
    }
    $upload = wp_upload_bits(basename($your_pdf_path), null, $response['body']);
    if (!empty($upload['error'])) {
        return false;
    }
    $file_path = $upload['file'];


    $attachments[] = $file_path;
    return $attachments;
}
```

Comment: Do i just add this to my functions.php, because when i do that, it says: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd_filter() in wp-content/themes/oceanwp/functions.php:1110
Stack trace:
#0 wp-settings.php(443): include()
#1 wp-config.php(90): require_once('/home/u1fnhv5/w...')
#2 wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/u1fnhv5/w...')
#3 wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/home/u1fnhv5/w...')
#4 wp-admin/theme-editor.php(10): require_once('/home/u1fnhv5/w...')
#5 {main}
  thrown

Comment: U missed letter a in front of dd_filter. Yes, add it to function.php